# Behavior of min function when the entries are equal ( the main reason here is because of the rounding up of the floating numbers)

Tags: matlab

This is the code:

```
a=[NaN, 0.0035; 2.0000 0.0025];
[~,b] = min (a(:,2));
```

so what is b? Inside of my project, b is 2. While if I run it outside of the project, I got b=1.

```
>> a=[NaN, 2; 1, 2];
>> a

a =

   NaN     2
     1     2

>> [~,b]=min(a(:,2))

b =

     1
```

EDIT: I highly doubt that there is something wrong with this min function in matlab or something else is wrong. Here is what I am doing.

K>> Q

```
Q =

  Columns 1 through 12

   -0.0053   -0.0015   -0.0014   -0.0014   -0.0014   -0.0014   -0.0014   -0.0014   -0.0014   -0.0014   -0.0014   -0.0014
   -0.0015   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045
   -0.0014   -0.0045       Inf   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045
   -0.0014   -0.0045   -0.0045       Inf   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045
   -0.0014   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045       Inf   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045
   -0.0014   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045       Inf   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045
   -0.0014   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045       Inf   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045
   -0.0014   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045       Inf   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045
   -0.0014   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045       Inf   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045
   -0.0014   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045       Inf   -0.0045   -0.0045
   -0.0014   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045       Inf   -0.0045
   -0.0014   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045   -0.0045       Inf
   -0.0053   -0.0014   -0.0014   -0.0014   -0.0014   -0.0014   -0.0014   -0.0014   -0.0014   -0.0014   -0.0014   -0.0014
   -0.0033   -0.0030   -0.0029   -0.0029   -0.0029   -0.0029   -0.0029   -0.0029   -0.0029   -0.0029   -0.0029   -0.0029
   -0.0053   -0.0015   -0.0014   -0.0014   -0.0014   -0.0014   -0.0014   -0.0014   -0.0014   -0.0014   -0.0014   -0.0014

  Columns 13 through 15

   -0.0053   -0.0033   -0.0053
   -0.0014   -0.0030   -0.0015
   -0.0014   -0.0029   -0.0014
   -0.0014   -0.0029   -0.0014
   -0.0014   -0.0029   -0.0014
   -0.0014   -0.0029   -0.0014
   -0.0014   -0.0029   -0.0014
   -0.0014   -0.0029   -0.0014
   -0.0014   -0.0029   -0.0014
   -0.0014   -0.0029   -0.0014
   -0.0014   -0.0029   -0.0014
   -0.0014   -0.0029   -0.0014
       Inf   -0.0033   -0.0053
   -0.0033       Inf   -0.0033
   -0.0053   -0.0033       Inf

(m,g)=min(Q(:))
```

Then I get m=-0.0053 and g=13 !!!!! Should do not g be 1 here ?

```
K>> g

g =

    13

K>> m

m =

   -0.0053
```

Can someone please help me? Or have you had similar experiences with matlab? Many thanks.

EDIT: (Just in case someone has the similar problem.) Here, the main reason why the min function behaves strangly is because of the errors. After opening up the workspace and take a close look at the values in the matrix Q, I found out that the (1,1) entry of the matrix is actually smaller than the minimum value of the matrix Q. Thanks very much for your time and attention.

Comment: When equal, it puts out the index of the first occurrence of the minimum element.

Comment: This behavior is clearly indicated in the [documentation for `min`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html#output_argument_i).

Comment: Yeah. I know. Somehow in my project, strange things happened. Thanks you all anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's the [index](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) of the matching elements. The syntax is well documented inside the GUI also, you can type `doc min` to see the output arguments.